# C Left shift unexpected behavior

Tags: c, microcontroller, bit-shift, sdcc

I have this code:

```
void GPIO_InitPortPin(uint8* PortControl, uint8 Pin, uint8 PinDir){
    *PortControl &= (~(1U << Pin));
    *PortControl |= (PinDir << Pin);
}
```

If the `PortControl` register is `11111111`, the first line should clear the bit of whatever the corresponding `Pin` is, but unexpectedly it clears all the register.

My Client Function is: `GPIO_InitPortPin(&TRISB, GPIO_PIN_0, GPIO_IN);`

`GPIO_PIN_0` and `GPIO_IN` are macros defined as follows:

```
#define GPIO_PIN_0    (0)
#define GPIO_PIN_1    (1)
...
#define GPIO_PIN_7    (7)

#define GPIO_OUT      (0)
#define GPIO_IN       (1)
```

So, I tried to cast Pin to `sint8`: `*PortControl &= (~(1U << (sint8) Pin));`

and it worked. Also, I tried to hard-code the Pin as `1` and it worked fine. I know the problem is that `Pin` is `uint8` or specifically to be `unsigned` since

`*PortControl &= (~(1U << 1));`
also worked fine. 
My Question is: why the right operand type affects the shifting operation, although I've red otherwise before(That RHS doesn't affect operation)?

Iam using SDCC compiler.

*Edit* : I've tested the function without casting on gcc and it worked as expected.

Comment: Sounds like an SDCC bug to me.

Comment: You migth try searching at https://sourceforge.net/p/sdcc/bugs/

Comment: This is questionable code as it may change the pin direction twice in a short space of time.  I recommend against using it.

Comment: What is the problem with that? @chux

Comment: `*PortControl` is a hardware register.  By flipping the pin direction in a short time, strange output may be seen on the port - even if only for a short time.  A better approach would either set the bit of clear the bit, not toggle the bit.

Comment: Consider `if (PinDir) *PortControl |= (1u<< Pin); else *PortControl &= ~(1u << Pin);`.  BTW: make certain `Pin` is 0-7.

Comment: Have you looked at the assembly generated by the sdcc?

Comment: If `*PortControl` is a hardware register, then *where's the `volatile`?!*

Comment: @AnttiHaapala As a port control, `volatile` is not the issue.  The port control does not change unless with CPU action.  `volatile` is very appropriate to the port IO register though.

Comment: @chux of course it can be an issue, all writes can be optimized out in a larger program if the compiler sees so

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Fair enough.  A subtle and correct point.

Comment: what is the value of `Pin` in the call? why not show a complete and verifiable example, instead of trying to make 100 people to guess about what could happen in your code without looking at it?

Comment: @LuisColorado Edited, and just `what is the value of Pin in the call? Why not show a complete and verifiable example?` would also be great.

Comment: @Mosaaleb, show yours first, as you are showing correct code.  There's no problem in your code, at least without showing more context.  This is a forum to deal with programming mistakes and errors, not to do the homework of students.   Please, show a full, complete and verifiable example, and we'll be able to show you where your mistakes are.

Comment: @Mosaaleb, telling things like _I've tested something_  and telling absolutely nothing at what tests your have made, and what results you received from them, is saying nothing about your testing.

Comment: @Mosaaleb, by the way, have you tried to print the values of parameters before the call and inside the function? just to see if they pass untouched... Have I to ask you whatever I imagine to test to see if you have done that test?  read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve or probably you'll get the question closed because of not following the SO rules.